# Norton Antivirus protection has expired popup windows keep on showing up over and over again even though I have uninstalled it

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, uninstall, popups, norton-antivirus

Every few days, this popup keeps returning even though I had already uninstalled Norton from my computer a few months ago (the pop-ups were a nuisance). Clicking on the "Uninstall" button takes me to the list of programs from the Control Panel, but I had already uninstalled Norton and it doesn't appear to be on the list.

Here is the message I keep getting.:

[image: Screenshot]

Around two years ago, I bought an Acer desktop computer with Windows 10 and Norton Security installed. Because of the constant popups from Norton, I uninstalled it, but then I got another pop-up, except this time it's from Windows! Constant frustration.

Comment: Time to uninstall the product.  If you are unable to uninstall the product, use the [tool](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v15972972) provided by Norton, to uninstall it properly.

Comment: @Ramhound OP says they uninstalled. The latter part of your suggestion is what I was going to suggest though. Most AV devs offer uninstall tools. This is what you should look for and run.

Comment: @music2myear - I only saw the screenshot and the text below it due to the size of the image and my brain being mush from having to debug hundreds of flip flop ICB over the course of the last 72 hours.

Comment: Looking at the image, Ramhound may be right. You should at least click the Uninstall button in that dialog. It may be you removed PARTS of Norton but not all, so start with the button there. If that doesn't work, use web searches to find the Norton removal tool on the Norton support site (don't download tools like that from anywhere but the brands own support website). Let us know if that works or not